# TinyMCE on Django Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, tinymce

I am trying to apply the TinyMCE rich text to only one form generated with Django. Upon doing so however it inserts another textarea within the form. What am I doing wrong?

Edited code

```
        <p><div id="AnswerBox">{{ form.as_p }}</div></p>

        $('.answers').load(url, function() {
            $('#AnswerBox').addClass('mceEditor', 
                function() {tinyMCE.init({
                    theme : "advanced",
                    mode : "specific_textareas",
                    editor_selector : "AnswerBox",
                    elements: "AnswerBox",
                    plugins : "fullpage",
                    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage",
                });
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the editor to the div that wraps the form. You need to add it to specific elements in the form - inputs and text areas. These are identified by the value of the `elements` option in the `TinyMCE.init()` function.

Look at [customising the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template), and adding your `mceEditor` class to the elements you want.

Alternatively you could write a little javascript to insert the class, and place it before your current js. Something like -

```
$('#yourForm textarea').addClass('mceEditor');
```

(You'll need to change your template -

```
<p><div id="yourForm">{{ form.as_p }}</div></p>
```

so the jquery selector works. Obviously you'll need to identify which fields you actually want the editor on).